# Problemas com o login CAKEPHP 2.6.1

Tags: cakephp, login

Estou com problemas com o login do site CakePHP, estou seguindo o exemplo que está descrito no site, porém ao informar qualquer usuário ou senha, mesmo que não esteja cadastrado no banco, ele permite acesso as funcionalidades.

Segue abaixo o código:

## User.php

```
<?php       

App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');



class User extends AppModel{

    public $validate = array(
            'username' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                    'message' => 'A username is required.'
                )
            ),
            'password' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                    'message' => 'A password is required.'
                )
            ),
            'role' => array(
                'valid' => array(
                    'rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'author')),
                    'message' => 'Please enter a valid role',
                    'allowEmpty' => false
                )
            ),

    );

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                    $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
            );
        }
        return true;
    }

}
?>
```

## UsersController.php

```
<?php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController{

    public function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('logout');
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->User->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
    }

    public function view($id = null){
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if(!$this->User->exists()){
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User'));
        }
        $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
    }

    public function add(){
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $this->User->create();
            if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The User has been saved.'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please try again.'));
            }
        }

    }

    public function edit($id = null){
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()){
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User'));
        }

        if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')){
            if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not been saved. Please, try again.'));
            }               
        }
        else{
            $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
            unset($this->request->data['User']['password']);
        }
    }

    public function delete($id = null){
        $this->request->allowMethod('post');

        $this->User->id = $id;
        if(!$this->User->exists()){
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User'));
        }

        if($this->User->delete()){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('User deleted.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User was not deleted.'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }

    public function login(){
        if ($this->request->is('post')){
            if($this->Auth->login()){
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }
    }

    public function logout(){
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
}
?>
```

## AppController.php

```
<?php

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {

    public function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
    }

    public $components = array(
            'Session',
            'Auth' => array(
                'loginRedirect' => array(
                    'controller' => 'posts',
                    'action'     => 'index' 
                ),
                'logoutRedirect' => array(
                    'controller' => 'pages',
                    'action'     => 'display',
                    'home'
                ),
                'authenticate' => array(
                    'Form' => array(
                            'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                    )
                )
            )
    );
}

?>
```

## Login.ctp

```
<div class="users form">
    <?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?>
        </legend>

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('username'); 
            echo $this->Form->input('password');
        ?>
    </fieldset>     
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>

</div>
```

Achei o Framework bem interessante, mas por algum motivo ele não está validando as informações que estão contidas no banco de dados.

Comment: Qual erro eh apresentado? Qual nome da sua tabela de usuários?

Comment: No seu AppController, tente remover esse trecho de código.  public function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
    }

Comment: O erro apresentado é que com qualquer usuário eu consigo me autenticar no sistema, mesmo que a senha esteja errada ou que o usuário não esteja cadastrado no banco. A função $this->Auth->login() sempre está retornando true. Removerei o código e postarei o reseultado.

Answer (score 1):

Remova na AppController a linha que esta no método beforeFilter.

```
$this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
```

E no UserController substitua:

```
$this->Auth->allow('logout');
```

por:

```
$this->Auth->allow('logout','login');
```

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado pela ajuda, consegui resolver os problemas que estavam dando. A solução dada acima, fez com que eu só consiga entrar no sistema através do login.

O outro problema que estava tendo, de mesmo informando um usuário errado e o sistema aceitava, resolvi da seguinte forma:

## UsersController.php

```
public function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('login', 'logout');

        //Se estiver logado, redireciona para página
        if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User')) {
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
        }
        else{
            $this->Session->delete('User');
        }
    }
```

O problema estava na sessão, pois os dados estavam ficando armazenados. Agora faço a verificação se o usuário já está logado, ele é redirecionado para a página principal e se a sessão expira um novo login é requisitado, apagando os dados armazenados anteriormente.

E ainda fiz a seguinte alteração:

## core.php

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'timeout' => 30, // A sessão irá expirar após 30 minutos de inatividade
));
```

Coloquei minha sessão para expirar com 30 minutos.

Agradeço a todos pelo apoio dado.